# Disabling the accelerometer from the manifest

Tags: android, manifest, accelerometer

I was wondering if there was a way to disable the accelerometer from the android manifest? From what I understand, you can use the uses-feature option to require the accelerometer, but that is about it.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think an app uses the accelerometer unless the permission is added so you wouldn't really need to disable it.

Comment: well for some reason when I hold my phone in portrait mode and run my app it crashes, but if I hold it in landscape mode it runs just fine. So, I have to assume that the accelerometer is being read all the time. Thanks for the speedy response.

Comment: do you have a progress dialog? in your manifest put android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in the activity it is crashing in

Comment: Progress Dialog? You mean for debugging? What exactly does the command above do? I tried it but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: the thing i told you to do fixes rotation crashes when your app has a loading dialog. do you have a stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: ok so by using android:screenOrientation = "landscape" I stopped it from force closing. Thanks for your suggestion, I was making it harder than I thought:).

Comment: Yeah, I'm making a game so there really is no need to be in portrait or landscape.

Comment: ok, but just keep the configchanges line in mind for the future. it's really useful!